# How to add share plugin properly in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-dependencies, flutter-plugin

```
Stack(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                      padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 25),
                      child: Center(
                          child: Text(
                        texts[index],
                        style: TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 22,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.normal,
                            color: Colors.black),
                      )),
                    ),
                    Positioned(
                      bottom: 0,
                      right: 0,
                      child: FlatButton(
                          onPressed: () {
                            Share.share(texts[index]);
                          },
                          child: Text(
                            "Share",
                            style: TextStyle(
                                color: Colors.white,
                                fontFamily: 'serif',
                                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                      )),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
```

Comment: Compiler message:
Error: Could not resolve the package 'share' in 'package:share/share.dart'.
lib/Screens/QoutesPage.dart:3:8: Error: Not found: 'package:share/share.dart'
import 'package:share/share.dart';
       ^
lib/Screens/QoutesPage.dart:97:33: Error: The getter 'Share' isn't defined for the class '_QoutesPageState'.
 - '_
                                Share.share('texts[index]');

Comment: Check your `pubspec.yaml` file. Make sure the formatting is proper and correct [share package](https://pub.dev/packages/share#-installing-tab-) is mentioned. After addition to `pubspec.yaml` run `pub get`

Answer (score 0):

first add this line in your pubspec file:- `url_launcher: ^5.4.2`

second use this code snipt :-

```
_launchURL() async {
 const url = 'https://flutter.dev';
 if (await canLaunch(url)) {
   await launch(url);
    } else {
      throw 'Could not launch $url';
    }
 }

final Uri _emailLaunchUri = Uri(
 scheme: 'mailto',
 path: 'smith@example.com',
   queryParameters: {
    'subject': 'Example Subject & Symbols are allowed!'
   }
);
```